# handling subtabs within tabs using different pages - asp .net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, tabs

I am teaching myself asp .net mvc3.
I want to create a user account page which has 3 tabs in it - say YourAddress, YourPhotos and YourProfile.

The 3rd tab (YourProfile) has 2 more subtabs in it ... ChangeDetails and DeactiaveAccount.

They are all dynamic pages and therefore I want to keep them as separate pages.

Basically the urls would be:

```
localhost/MyHome/YourAddress
localhost/MyHome/YourPhotos
localhost/MyHome/YourProfile/ChangePassword
localhost/MyHome/YourProfile/DeactivateAccount
```

(As requested I have changed the generic tab1, tab2 etc to something in real-world scenario)

I am planning to do something like this:

```
public class MyHomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /MyHome/Tab1

        public ActionResult Tab1()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /MyHome/Tab2

        public ActionResult Tab2()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /MyHome/Tab3

        public ActionResult Tab3()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

How do I handle the subtabs of YourProfile? How do I call a controller within a controller?

What is the best way to accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a real world scenario what the tabs will have ?

Comment: Use jquery. Here is an example http://www.stackdotnet.com/2011/11/taband-subtab-in-mvc-by-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have separate action method for each tab item in your controller.

```
public class MyHomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult YourAddress()
  {
     return View();
  }
  public ActionResult YourPhotos()
  {
     return View();
  }
  public ActionResult YouProfile()
  {
     return VieW();
  }
  public ActionResult ChangePassword()
  {
     return View();
  }
  public ActionResult DeActivate()
  {
     return View();
  }
}
```

For the sub tab content, define that route in the global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute("ChangePass","YourProfile/ChangePassword", 
                      new { controller="MyHome", action="ChangePassword" });
routes.MapRoute("DeActivate","YourProfile/DeActivate", 
                      new { controller="MyHome", action="DeActivate" });
routes.MapRoute(
           "Default", 
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Always use `Url.Action` Html Helper method to render a path to an action method.

```
<div id="tabs"> 
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("YourAddress","MyHome")">Address</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("YourPhotos","MyHome")">Photos</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Tripping: I would use areas to if the functinality is entirly different.( Ex : Normal users Ecom portal and Admin users Ecom portal)

Comment: thanks @shyju ... works like a charm but I still don't understand how the routing works when I click the link.

Comment: that's fine ... I was getting confused with Html.Action

Comment: I can see this controller getting quite fat, anyway to break it down? i.e. `ProfileController`, `PhotoController` etc.

Comment: @LukeHutton: Totally agree. As it grows,i would definitely separate it.  I am a strong believer in keeping controllers thin. The point i was trying to show the OP was to keep the methods in separate service layer and just call it from the controller action.